# Экранирование зарезервированного слова в Питон

Tags: python

Есть метод, один из его аргументов имеет имя, совпадающее с зарезервированным словам языка. Мне нужно явно задать этот аргумент при вызове метода. Можно ли как-то отменить резервирования слова\экранировать конкретно в этом месте или единственный путь - указывать все аргументы метода "через запятую", не используя их имена? А может, есть способ "не маяться дурью?" Задача состоит в том, чтобы получить новости по списку сообществ. Причем используется версия апи до 5.13 (точно не могу сказать, какая)

[image: Собственно, код]

Comment: как минимум вы можете воспользоваться функционалом kwargs (положить все аргументы в словарь и развернуть с помощью `**args`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Экранирование [невозможно](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords). Но, как уже написал @etki, можно попробовать использовать [kwargs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments):

```
kwargs = {
           'from': next_from,
           'filters': 'post',
           'source_ids': ', '.join(groups_list),
           'count': 100,
           'timeout': 10
         }
newsfeed = vkapi.newsfeed.get(**kwargs)
```